# How to save a dataframe result in hive table with different name on each iteration using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of which I am storing the result in hive table using saveAsTable command. I want my code to run for multiple countries and store the result as a table with different name for each country.

Example: Lets suppose I have a variable with countries name list

```
options=['AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'CA' ,'CH']
s=input("Enter your country code")
if s in options:
  country_cd=s
else:
 print("invalid country code")
```

Now based on country_cd variable I want to save the result in df

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("amankeshar.table_{country_cd}")
```

The table should be stored with the country name on it.
Need help in achieving it.

Comment: so what issue did you face at the moment?

Comment: Maybe this answer might help future readers https://stackoverflow.com/a/55812695/5757129